# Basic "Alert Box" and "Multiplying Input with 5" in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Its a simple coding of The User inserting a Number in the text field and the Input is multiplied by 5 and the Result is shown in an Alert Box.

Due to some reason, it is not working properly. Please help.

I am a complete beginner but I did try some changes but it didn't work out.

```js
function myAlertMath() {
  var userNumber = document.getElementById("mathInput").value;
  alert("your number x 5 is " + userNumber * 5);
}
```

```html
<p> JavaScipt Alert Test</p>
<button onclick="alert('The Test Worked');">Alert Test</button>
<input id=mathInput " type="number "/> <button onclick="myAlertMath() ">Multiply*5</button>
<p id="test "><p>
```

1. Clicking on the Alert Box displays an Alert Box
2. Entering a Number in the text field and clicking the Multiply*5 displays the answer in an Alert Box

Comment: What isn't working? Seems to work for me?

Comment: It's working fine here (Firefox last on Windows10)

Comment: Your code is working fine iam getting answer what is expected

Comment: If I click the "Multiply*5" Box nothing is being displayed.

Comment: @CodingNoob what does your alert show? Can you explain what you mean by it "not working properly"?

Comment: @NickParsons If I enter a number in the Text Field and Click on the "multiply*5", there should be an Alert Box displaying the Answer.

Comment: @Kaddath If I click on F12 it shows that a mistake on the line "var userNumber = document.getElementById("mathInput").value;"

Comment: I corrected the mistake. It was a "" missing. Thank You @Kaddath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to a typo in the `input` tag. There is a double quote missing after `id=`.

Comment: Thank You So Much. I need one more help, can I ask you to help once more please.

Comment: @CodingNoob You shouldn't ask different questions in one post, this is so that people in the future can find easily existing answers when they search on the web. If you have another question, you should create a new one.

Comment: Alright. I will remember that. 1st time StackOverflow user.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.